# Show HTML in Javascript If else statement

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, document.write

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - document.write error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236353/javascript-document-write-error)

I have a piece of Javascript that I'm using that checks to see if a div is a certain style and then runs an if else statement:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') {
        document.write('<a href="#show" class="show_hide"><img src="images/show-more-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45"></a>');
    } else {
        document.write('<a href="#show" class="show_hide"><img src="images/show-less-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45"></a>');
    }
};
```

This works OK, but it only shows this HTML image on the screen. I need it to add the HTML to the existing code on the page.

Many thanks

Comment: Avoid `document.write()` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: When you use document.write after the page load, it replaces all of the page content.

Answer (score 7):

Use `appendChild` or `innerHTML`

example:

```
document.getElementById("elemId").innerHTML = '<a href="#show" class="show_hide"><img src="images/show-less-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45"></a>'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src='images/show-more-arrow.jpg';
wrapper.appendChild(image);
```

Something like this.

Comment: +1 for not using `innerHTML`.

Comment: innerHTML is not bad and when multiple nodes should be add, it's more performant