# Write html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - document.write error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236353/javascript-document-write-error)

I want to write html into javascript.
I am sure this question, has been asked ofter, I know its simple but I can't figure it out.

I tried this:

```
  <script>
  document.write("<h1>This is a heading</h1>");
  document.write("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");
  </script>
```

But it removes all the other html.

I know this is noob question, I pretty unexperienced at javascript...

Comment: You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) and/or [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Comment: When you get the hang of js this is my favorite: [http://beebole.com/pure/](http://beebole.com/pure/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>This is a heading</h1>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<p>This is a paragraph</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say i have a div on my page and i want to add content to it:

```
<div id="myDiv"><div>
```

I can use javascript to do so:

```
<script>
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var myHtmlString = "<h1>This is a heading</h1>";
myHtmlString += "<p>This is a paragraph</p>"
div.innerHTML = myHtmlString;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it breaks the rest of the html code.

Comment: @HamadaBadran It breaks the HTML code?

Comment: @HamadaBadran there is no way it can break the code. Please explain how