# Why does my javascript button dissapear onlick(in-line method)

Tags: javascript, button

I know some javascript but never quite understood why this code makes the buttons disappear.

```
<input type="button" name="clickable" value="Click me!" onclick="clicked();">
```

OR

```
<button onclick="clicked();">Clickity</button>
```

Here is my function

```
function clicked() {
    document.write("Thank you");
}
```

As you can see it is not telling the element to hide or anything like that. Can someone explain this? A solution would be nice.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tumoboxo/2/)

Comment: don't use document.write, its a bad practice and that's erasing your other stuff

Comment: okay, so document.write clears the screen

Comment: @unableToCompile, only after the document has been fully parsed. You can run that line in line with the regular flow of the document, but within function calls, it will erase everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write overwrites the existing HTML on the page.  You could try something like this:

Script:

```
function clicked() {
    document.getElementById('myOutput').innerHTML="Thank you";
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" name="clickable" value="Click me!" onclick="clicked();">
<div id="myOutput"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you write your document to "Thank you"

Try to use `alert` or `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

You executed `document.write()` after the DOM was loaded and ready, which writes over the HTML of the entire page. [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236353/javascript-document-write-error/3236373#3236373) will help elaborate.